# kapt.use.worker.api is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

After build I get this warning:

> 'kapt.use.worker.api' is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in Kotlin 1.8 release.

Knowing that I have in my gradle.properties :

```
kapt.use.worker.api=true
```

and in my Module level build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

then, what is the alternative to the deprecated line ?

Answer (score 12):

This option is deprecated and you should simply remove it from your gradle.properties.

That doesn't break kapt, it is happening to continue supporting next versions of the JDK.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48827/Remove-kaptuseworkerapi-property

Comment: It's been a while since I removed that line and everything is working fine, thank you(I'm just waiting for kotlin 1.8 to test and then accept the answer).

Answer (score 0):

> kapt.use.worker.api=true

`true` is default since kotlin 1.3.70 and flag will be removed starting kotlin 1.8
ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48826

you can safely remove the flag since the value is true anyway,

Can someone add here, what (if any) changes are required if this flag was false?